# Execute encrypted script

Tags: python, encryption, base64

I have a python script that reads deciphers base64 encrypted strings, im TRYING to have it so when the string is decrpyted its contents are executed.

```py
def crypexec(jargon):
#push base64 through decryptor
 decipher = base64.b64decode(jargon)
#execute instructions in the encoded string
 exec decipher

ferret= unicode("""DQpzZXJ2ZXIgPSBzb2NrZXQuc29ja2V0KHC5BRl9JTkVULCBzb2NrZXQuU09DS19TVFJF..
```

then i attempt to call it back with

```
crypexec(ferret)
```

Does not work

[This](http://code.google.com/p/0xic-zex/source/browse/trunk/Python/BD/bd_shell.py) is what ferret looks like unecrypted. Of course i removed the import portions of the ciphered script before running it, still cant understand why it doesnt work.

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, it is encoding.

Comment: base64 is to encryption as wet toilet paper is to drying yourself off after a shower.

Comment: Please indent your Python code properly using four spaces.

Comment: *Does not work* is not enough information to help you. Could you post a traceback please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\0xic-zex\Python\BD\encryptme.py", line 44, in <module>
    crypexec(ferret)
  File "C:\0xic-zex\Python\BD\encryptme.py", line 22, in crypexec
    decipher = base64.b64decode(jargon)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding

c:\0xic-zex\Python\BD>

Comment: Encoded, encrypted. Same thing, different word. ALL that matters is the execution of the contents not what i say......................

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the string is correct? Not missing a few characters at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing padding on your base64 **encoded** string...

you can try adding an "=" to the end of your string (maybe as many as 3 "=" signs)

if that doesnt work you may have encrypted it using a different padding symbol than the standard "=" .... how did you **encode** the string?

try encoding it with python should resolve this issue

```
import base64
my_enc = base64.b64encode(""" 
def hello():
     print 'hello world!'
hello() """)

exec(base64.b64decode(my_enc))
```